# Creating book like layout in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, layout

I am working on an web application which requires its data to be displayed in a Book like format.The data is something like this

```
Menu{
  String menuName;
  List<String> subMenu;
}
```

I have used jquery to display data in book format.The divs are generated dynamically.
Steps followed :

```
1. created a single array with menuName and its subMenus.like completeData = [menuObj1,"submenu1","subMenu2",menuObj2,"subMenu1","subMenu2","subMenu3",...];  
2. First fill left Container  
      For Each value in completeData
      if it is obj then create a new Div menuDiv and display its menuName and append to container.
check container height if it exceeds then break.

      if it is String then create a new subMenuSpan and append it to subMenuDiv and finally append it to container.
check container height if it exceeds then break and store the index.

3. Now fill the right container
      start from the storedIndex from Left Container and continue the same process.
```

Code : For Left Container

```
for(var i=index;i<completeData.length;i++){

    if(typeof completeData[i] == 'string'){
        // subMenu
        menuSpan = $('<div id="menuSpan">').text(completeData[i]);
        if(typeof completeData[i-1] == 'string'){
            menuSpan.appendTo(menuDiv);

            // Break if container height exceeds and store the index.
            if($('#menu-inner-left').height() >= height){
                menuSpan.remove();
                rightIndex=i;
                break;
            }
        }else{
            menuDiv = $('<div id="menuDiv">').appendTo('#menu-inner-left');
            menuSpan.appendTo(menuDiv);

            // Break if container height exceeds and store the index.
            if($('#menu-inner-left').height() >= height){
                 menuDiv.remove();
                 rightIndex=i;
                 break;
            }
        }
    }else{
        // Menu Name
        menuNameDiv = $('<div id="menuNameDiv">').appendTo('#menu-inner-left');
        $('<div>').text(completeData[i].menuName).appendTo(menuNameDiv).css('float','left');

        // Break if container height exceeds and store the index.
        if($('#menu-inner-left').height() >= height){
              menuDiv.remove();
              rightIndex=i;
              break;
        }
     }
  }
```

Code  : For Right Container
Start from Index Stored in Left Container and then same process

```
for(var i=rightIndex;i<completeData.length;i++){
    // Same Code of Left Container
}
```

final image of the result
[image]

Now the Book View is displayed properly But the problems is : 
1. Takes lot of time to display as it is creating lots of divs.

I tried creating divs in plain Javascript but still no effect.
Now we are shifting to angular JS to avoid creating divs with jquery.Will it affect the loading time.

what could be the other ways to avoid creating lots of divs and reduce loading time.

Comment: [Turn.js](http://www.turnjs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

This is not the solution just an approach to achieve as per your scree capture.
Instead of loading all the data at once try to store that data in cache after getting from the source, On every next page/ Prev page click write a callback that will get only current page data so that you can decrease rendering time. Or You can use some plugins for this kind of like @adeno specified
Turn.js.

```
Menu{
  data:[ 
       String menuName;
       List<String> subMenu;
      ]
  pagingObject:{
   pageNumber<int>,
   currentPage<int>,
   pageSize<int>

  }
}
```